# How to use AKMixer with both AKPlayer and AKMetronome at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm currently making a metronome app, it uses AKMetronome for the core part since it has the callback function, I need the callback function to visualize the beat, I also want to use it for customized click sound (and I'll mute the original AKMetronome sound, but it'll still play, just without the original sound).

Now, I have two wav files which are customized click sound, there will be two AKPlayers to play it, and the AKPlayers need to be triggered on every AKMetronome beat's callback.
Since AKPlayer and AKMetronome are both need to be played, I put them in an AKMixer, like this:

```swift
        let mixer = AKMixer(playerA, playerB, metronome)
        AudioKit.output = mixer
```

and the callback will call this func:

```swift
    func playAudio() {
            playerA.play()
            playerB.play()
    }
```

Then, when playerA.play() is executed, it'll crash.
This is the error message:

```
AURemoteIO::IOThread (11): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xffff9ffffdb0e360)
```

[same error message in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PnfM.png)

If I only put one of the AKPlayer object or AKMetronome in the AKMixer, then it works fine.
I can't understand the error message, also don't know why this happens.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full code:

```swift
    var playerA: AKPlayer!
    var playerB: AKPlayer!
    var clickA: AKAudioFile?
    var clickB: AKAudioFile?
    var metronome: AKMetronome?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        prepareAudio()
        metronome!.start()
    }

    func prepareAudio() {
        clickA = try? AKAudioFile(readFileName: "Click1A.wav")
        clickB = try? AKAudioFile(readFileName: "Click1B.wav")

        playerA = AKPlayer(audioFile: clickA!)
        playerA.buffering = .always
        playerB = AKPlayer(audioFile: clickB!)
        playerB.buffering = .always

        //metronome
        metronome = AKMetronome.init()
        metronome!.subdivision = 4
        metronome!.frequency1 = 1000
        metronome!.frequency2 = 800
        metronome!.tempo = 60
        metronome!.callback = {
            self.playAudio()
        }

        let mixer = AKMixer(playerA, playerB, metronome)
        AudioKit.output = mixer
        do {
            try AudioKit.start()
        } catch {
            print("audiokit start fail!")
        }
    }

    func playAudio() {
            playerA.play()
            playerB.play()
    }
```